# UIButton with added Gradient cuts off

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uibutton, cagradientlayer

So I am applying a gradient to a UIButton via an extension:

```
extension UIButton {

    func addGradient(withColors colors:[CGColor]) {
      let layer_: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
      layer_.frame = self.bounds
      layer_.colors = colors
      layer_.shouldRasterize = true
      layer_.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
      self.layer.insertSublayer(layer_, at: 0)
    }

}
```

Applying it to the UIButton via:

```
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton! {
    didSet {
        startButton.backgroundColor = ECConstants.GenericColors.buttonOrange
        startButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        startButton.addGradient(withColors: [UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor])
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, on the iPad Pro 12.9 inch (iOS 10.1), it appears to cut short of the width of the button.  I've also tried to apply it in viewDidLoad, to no avail.

[image: iPad Pro UIButton Gradient not full width]

So my question is how do I make the gradient go all the way across? Or where is the best place to set a gradient?

Comment: Try logging the width of the button to console during a tap. This can confirm the button is as wide as you expect (looks like the issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension for adding gradient to a button is all correct, what you need to fix is where you set the gradient.

Move

```
startButton.backgroundColor = ECConstants.GenericColors.buttonOrange
startButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
startButton.addGradient(withColors: [UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor])
```

to `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

The reason for this is because once `viewDidAppear()` is called, all the view's sizes are calculated.

For though-roughness: (Supporting device rotation)

Make sure you recalculate your sublayer size in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. Your button will change size on device rotation, so you need to manually change the sublayer size as well.

Comment: I ended up moving the `startButton.addGradient` call from the `didSet` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and that seems to work.